# Python 3 regex word boundary unclear

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am using a regex to find the string 'my car' and detect up to four words before it. My reference text is:

```
my house is painted white, my car is red.
A horse is galloping very fast in the road, I drive my car slowly.
```

if I use the regex:

```
re.finditer(r'(?:\w+[ \t,]+){0,4}my car',txt,re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
```

I am getting the expected results.For example: house is painted white, my car

if I use the regex:

```
re.finditer(r'(?:\w+\b){0,4}my car',txt,re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
```

I am getting only: 'my car' and 'my car'
That is, I am not getting up to four words before it.
Why I cannot use the \b to match the words in the group {0,4}?

Comment: `\b` is zero-width assertion, it won't match spaces/commas etc after your words.

Comment: The regex for a word boundary is `(?:(?:^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9_]))(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_])|(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9_])(?:$|(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9_])))` maybe you can spot the mistake you've made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\b` is a *zero-width assertion* [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) matching a *location* between the start of string and a word char, between a non-word char and a word char, between a word char and a non-word char and between a word char and end of string. **It does not *consume* the text**.

The `(?:\w+\b){0,4}` just matches an empty string since there is no 1+ word chasrs followed with a word boundary before `my car`.

Instead, you may want to match 1+ non-word chars that will effectively imitate a word boundary:

```
(?:\w+\W+){0,4}my car\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kP5nD4/2)

Comment: Surely, you can use word boundary *after* `car`, to avoid matching `carriage`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
(?:\b\w+\W+){4}
\b(?:my\ car)\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/iB6xL0/3).

---

In `Python` this will be:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'''
                (?:\b\w+\W+){0,4}
                \b(?:my\ car)\b
                ''', re.VERBOSE)

string = """
my house is painted white, my car is red.
A horse is galloping very fast in the road, I drive my car slowly.
"""
words = rx.findall(string)
print(words)
# ['house is painted white, my car', 'the road, I drive my car']
```

Comment: You cannot fail to get a word boundary between a `\w` and `\W`, thus, `\b` inside `\w+\b\W+` is redundant.

Comment: Yes, by definition `(?<=\W)(?=\w)` is one word boundary. And therefore `(?:\b\w+\W+){0,4}` is `\b\w+\W+\b\w+\W+\b\w+\W+\b\w+\W+` for a full {4}. Then `\W+\b\w+` is equal to `\W+\w+`